# Data Redundancy with multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, database, schema

So I have created a user notification system, and I have a user_notifications table structured like so:

```
id
receiver_id
sender_id
action
action_type
entity_id
timestamp
```

Now, there are values in other tables connected to a notification through the 'entity_id' column. So let's say I also have this table called **videos_watched**:

```
video_id
user_id
time_watched_for
```

They are connected from **user_notifications**.entity_id to **videos_watched**.video_id

What I'm trying to decide is whether it's a bad thing to store the data in the second table as well. Should I treat the **user_notifications** table as an interaction table, rather than a place to actually reliably store user data?

Comment: no one can possibly answer this without knowing the volume of usage. Rule of thumb, the less usage your system has, the closer it suppose to be to the theories (normalization, etc) the more volume u have, u will find yourself needing to break theories

Answer (score 2):

The way I would approach this task is by breaking the data you are recording into manageable and logical chunks (although this is influenced by the amount of usage and the actual information you are wanting to pull out).

For instance, if the situation is that you are recording the following types of data:

- user information (email, id, name etc)
- videos (id, title, filename etc)
- videos watched (video_id, user_id, time_watched_for)

Then it may make sense to store the data in separate tables so that the information is separated in a meaningful way.

So in that sense it would also make sense to have you initial table for notifications (although this looks more like a notification logs table):

- notification table (id, receiver_id, sender_id, action, action_type,
  entity_id, timestamp)

Essentially, storing the data in a separate table isn't a bad idea, as long as there is a meaningful or logical reason to store it there such as logical data separation.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, it's a bad idea to have redundant data in your database (non-normalized) because:

- It takes up more space.
- It's more cumbersome to maintain and takes longer to write (you are writing the same data to multiple places).
- You can get an inconsistent database (like if you mess up the point above and don't write to all the places you need to).

The only reason to ever have redundant data that I can think of is because you absolutely need a performance boost for some kind of join that you will be doing and reading from all the time.  If you have redundant data, you can eliminate the join/lookup and read straight from a single table.